# Creating an outlook appointment with attachments

Tags: vb.net, outlook, exchangewebservices, appointment

So i've been trying for days now to create an appointment using EWS and ExchangeServiceBinding

i've managed most properties for the said appointment but the attachment has proven to be a real pain

So far i've managed to create the appointment and add the attachment but only to the original appointment (the one i have in my inbox) and not to the other people.

I've tried various methods that (apparently) works for messages :
Create the appointment with the attachment   (doesnt add the attachment to anyone)
Create the appointment, send it, modify the appointment to add the attachment (modify it for me)
Create the appointment as a draft, add the attachment, send it (send it, modify it for me, send another one without the attachment)

The server guys dont want us to push any additionnal DLLs or software on the servers
(doesnt even have office DLLs)

And now you see me rather stumped as to what to try next...
Hope that was precise enough...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, for anyone encountering this problem, i've found out that updating the appointment twice does the trick

do the appointment, without attendees
add the attachment which ends in a request on the server
change the attendees and update.

Voila!